# find index of array B that includes element of array A

Tags: javascript

here is the arrays:

```
array A = ["a", "b", "c"];
array B = ["e", "f", "a"];
```

I want to find the index(s) of the element in array B which is equal to the element of array A. here it is a so the index is 2...

Comment: I'm sorry, but the question is unclear to me. May you please post an example and the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

For each item in B, look through A. If it exists in A, push the index.

```js
var indices = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arrayA.length; j++) {
    if (arrayB[i] === arrayA[j]) {
      indices.push(i);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` and `filter()`

```js
var A = ["a", "b", "c"];
var B = ["e", "f", "a"];
var indexArr = B.map((i, idx) => {
  if(A.includes(i)) return idx;
}).filter(i => i);
console.log(indexArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ES6: you can do this with `forEach()` and `indexOf()`

```
const A = ["a", "b", "c"];
const B = ["e", "f", "a"];
let C = [];
A.forEach((v, k)=>{
  let index = B.indexOf(v);
  if (index > 0) {
    C.push(index);
  }
});
```